# xsl into Google sheet automatically

Tags: excel, google-sheets, automation

I get every day an Excel Sheet from another department. Now I need the Excel Sheet as a Google Sheet.

Manual it is possible to change Excel to Google Sheet, but can I do this automatically maybe with a time trigger (once a day).
The new excel list should be exported in Google Sheets.

Thanks in advance!

Jonas

Comment: Do you mean that you receive the sheet in an email? Where should it be exported? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can change settings in Google drive which will automatically convert uploaded excel files to google sheet.